# Referencing components from a subclassMap

Tags: fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I am trying to reference a component from a subclass map but am getting the following exception

"Visitor attempted on unresolved componented reference 'Weight', referenced from property 'Weight' of 'RecipeFermentable', unable to continue."

```
public class RecipeFermentableMap : SubclassMap<RecipeFermentable>
{
    public RecipeFermentableMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Pppg);
        Component(x => x.Weight);

        References(x => x.Recipe);
    }
}
```

This work when I do it with a normal ClassMap but stopped working after re-factoring into a SubclassMap.